# Change Image source dynamically(FLEX)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

New to AS/FLEX, actually couldn't find much information on google about this simple question. I have an Image in mxml, with a source pointing to a variable that has an embedded source as follows

```
<mx:Image id="image" source="{imageSource}"/>

[Bindable]
[Embed(source="pic.png")]
public var imageSource:Class
```

This is good for loading a single image, but when the image is pressed, I want the source to point to a new variable that has a different source embedded

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source="pic.png")]
public var imageSource2:Class
```

When image is clicked I have something like

```
image.source = imageSource2;
image.validateNow();
```

This kind of updates my image but not immediately after .validateNow(), if I go through the debugger and stop right after that point, its still the same image. It seems to update after the entire method finishes, but the idea behind this method is that in the beginning it will start with one image, and before it ends it will switch to another image, so the image changes twice in the single call

Comment: `[Embed]` is a static linkage, you are basically asking for dynamic linkage. If you are seeking for change of several static (that is, you don't plan to ever change them) pictures, you can embed them all and then instantiate another class out of the embedded images. If they are too big for static linkage, or you don't know what would they be, use URL loading method to get the image in your app. Can't say for `[Bindable]`, but you sure cannot bind a class directly. You might try binding a variable of type `Bitmap` and then use either method of populating that bitmap.

Comment: What I want to do is pre load all my assets, in this case 4 static images. I used embed because I thought thats how to pre load, so there is no delay in showing picture. Can you show code example of how I do this? I only half understand what you are saying, again I am completely new to AS/FLEX. All other google/stackoverflow questions on the same topic simply said to change the source url.

Comment: Hmm. In this case, yes, embed all 4, and then use code similar to [this](http://bittyferrari.blogspot.ru/2011/02/flex-4-assing-bitmapdata-to-image.html) to assign a proper bitmap to the variable.

Comment: Why do you want to change the image twice in a single call?  There isn't any point to that; the second image would flash by too quickly to be seen.  The third image would override the second one in less than 1/10 of a second (i.e. however long it takes the processor to execute the instructions in your function).